# Android Camera Intent EXTRA_OUTPUT being ignored?

Tags: android, android-camera

I have been using the camera intent and the EXTRA_OUTPUT to specify where to save the file to, and as of a few weeks ago, it started being ignored!
This app worked a few weeks previously, and no OS upgrades had occurred in that time..

After spending 13 hours trying to figure out what was going on with this camera API...

I may have figured out the source of the problem:

If there are any apps installed on the phone that interact with, or intercept the camera API, some of the API may break!

I discovered this after a 13 hour debugging marathon, trying all the possible API combinations, and following all the suggestions on stackoverflow..

My hands were getting tired holding the phone, so I built a phone stand out of a coathanger to anchor the phone to my desk, with the camera pointed at a jar of peanut butter.

In a stroke of luck, as I was debugging with my photos of peanut butter, the Google Goggles App popped up a notification saying it had "recognized" something
in my image!

This prompted me to IMMEDIATELY uninstall google goggles, and all of a sudden, images start saving to my custom Uri like they used to!!!

This was on a Samsung Stratosphere.

I'm posting this in the form of a question in the hopes that it helps someone else!!

p.s. - I'd like to thank google goggles, and trader joes crunchy peanut butter for being intertwined enough to give me a clue as to who was screwing up my API.

Comment: And I'd just like to shout out to Joel Spolsky for making me wait 3 minutes in between responding to people with similar problems.. thereby forcing me to post my solution in the form of a question.

It's not enough that I am contributing to your database of solutions of my own free will and on my own dime.. but I get to be treated like a 3rd world spammer.
Thanks, bro.